# C++ Exam Questions on pointers and references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm revising for an exam, this was on a past paper. I'm unsure of the answer to the last part (and all the lecturers for the module have buggered off for the week...)

The question involves some common parts of C and C++, given the following;

```
void MyIncrementFirst(int * i) {
  (*i)++;
}

void MyIncrementSecond(int i) {
  i++;
}

void MyIncrementThird(int & i) {
  i++;
}

void MyIncrementFourth(int ** i) {
  *i = new int(0);
}

void MyIncrementFifth(int *& i) {
  i = new int(69);
}
```

and running it using this:

```
int * a = new int(42);
cout << "Result" << endl;
MyIncrementFirst(a);
cout << "first " << *a << endl;
MyIncrementSecond(*a);
cout << "second " << *a << endl;
MyIncrementThird(*a);
cout << "third " << *a << endl;
MyIncrementFourth(&a);
cout << "fourth " << *a << endl;
MyIncrementFifth(a);
cout << "fifth " << *a << endl;
```

They ask about what it does and what output does it give. I understand this, but the question goes on to ask this:

(iii) Assume line 1 in the code given in part a(i) is replaced by the following:

```
int a = 42;
```

What modifications would you make to the code in a(i) so that it will compile and execute to produce the same output (using the same functions)?

We *assume* this we are meant to adapt the calls to the function to something like the following:

```
int a = 42;
cout << "Result" << endl;
MyIncrementFirst(&a);
cout << "first " << a << endl;
...
```

But I can't work out the answers for the `MyIncrementFourth` and `MyIncrementFifth`

Comment: how about `int *b = &a; MyIncrementFourth(&b); MyIncrementFifth(b);`? (You don't have to play fair, you only have to win :-)

Comment: That was the conclusion several people reached, but it's a 15 mark question, which makes it seems rather little work for 3 marks for changing a function from *a to a and declaring a new pointer of int variable. And it also makes it seem like an "undo my changes" question which also seems odd..

Answer (score 0):

Expending on comment...

A ***correct*** answer would be:

```
int *b = &a;
MyIncrementFourth(&b);
MyIncrementFifth(b);
```

You rightfully stated that this seems too simple regarding the context of the question, so let's try to dig into the details.

In `MyIncrementFourth`, the function receives a `int **` parameter. That parameter is expected to hold a value which is interpreted as:

1. A memory address (pointer), where exists ->
2. A memory address (pointer), where exists ->
3. An `int` value.

Suppose our `a` variable is not optimized into a register and actually has a reserved memory address at 0xC0000000. We need to put this value in another variable and pass that new variable's address as the input value of the function. So we need to allocate some new memory to hold the value 0xC0000000. Suppose that new address is at 0xC0000004. Now we can actually call `MyIncrementFourth((int **)0xC0000004);` and it would work, but it is inevitable that we have the 2 addresses available. The easiest way to do that is by `int *b =&a;`